# Using paired zebra datepicker and date in the past to today

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using Zebra Datepicker and have a start date and end date. I am looking for help with code that would help me with this:

Start date should be up to today (should not be in the future)
End date should be from the start of the Start date choice to today (No future date).

I started with this but cannot seem to get any further.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $zdp = $('#element').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
$('#from').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: false,
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    view: 'years',
    show_icon: true,
    pair: $('#to')
    });
$('#to').Zebra_DatePicker({
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    view: 'years',
    direction: true
});
```

});

Answer (score 3):

I just came to this issue myself and solved it easily by reading the zebra datepicker documentation:

> A positive or negative integer: n (a positive integer) creates a
>   future-only calendar beginning at n days after today; -n (a negative
>   integer) creates a past-only calendar ending n days before today; if n
>   is 0, the calendar has no restrictions. use boolean true for a
>   future-only calendar starting with today and use boolean false for a
>   past-only calendar ending today.

So your code should change to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $zdp = $('#element').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
    $('#from').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: true,
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        view: 'years',
        show_icon: true,
        pair: $('#to')
    });
    $('#to').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: true
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        view: 'years',
    }); 
});
```

The only change made is that I changed the direction of #from to true. As stated in the documentation your #to direction is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just add -1 in direction instead of false

```
$('#from').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: -1,
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        view: 'years',
        show_icon: true,
        pair: $('#to')
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an external library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you should format the current date (today) for using it in the `direction` option of the second datepicker this way:

```js
var end_date = moment().format("m/d/Y");

$('#to').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: [true, end_date]
  format: 'm/d/Y',
  view: 'years',
});
```

This way, the second datepicker will start with the date selected in first datepicker, and will end today since `end_date` will have the current date.