# zebra datepicker direction - past up to certain date

Tags: date, datepicker, direction, setting, zebra-ui-framework

I want to set up [Zebra datepicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) plugin in a way that it has enabled all past dates up to certain specified date. I found out this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050800/using-paired-zebra-datepicker-and-date-in-the-past-to-today) that explains how to do that if that border date is today. But, if the border date is lets say 1 month in the past or so, how should I define the "direction" option?

So basically I want to restrict date selection from the "beginning of time" up to some specified date.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you can see they described it in the documentation. Try out this code:

```
$('#datepicker-example5').Zebra_DatePicker({
  // remember that the way you write down dates
  // depends on the value of the "format" property!
  direction: ['2012-08-01', '2012-08-12']
});
```

The example is listed in topic "Demos" (Sub-Topic 5) here: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

Comment: "I want to restrict date selection from the "beginning of time" up to some specified date". I wanted something like this [any point since the beginning of time, specified date]. And this seems rather impossible to do with Zebra datepicker. You need to specify a beginning date in this case and I did a "hack" with that and specified a date far in the past. At least it seems like a hack to me... that you need to hardcode a date when you just want all dates up to specified one enabled.